# Testing code with dropbox interaction

Tags: python-3.x, dropbox-api

I have bunch of code that download file from dropbox periodically.

```
def photos_list(dbx: Dropbox, folder: str, cursor: str = None, recursive: bool=False) -> Generator[FileMetadata, None, None]:
    has_more = True
    while has_more:
        if cursor is not None:
            files = dbx.files_list_folder_continue(cursor)
        else:
            files = dbx.files_list_folder(folder; recursive=recursive)

        for file in files.entries:
            if isinstance(file, FileMetadata):
                yield file
        cursor = files.cursor
        has_more = files.has_more
```

I'm using `unittest.TestCase` class inheritance to test my code. I have separate as much as I can dropbox interaction, that way I can test my code without calling dropbox. But I would like to test function like `photos_list` what is the best way ? Mocking dropbox with `unittest.mock` ? I've read that I should use pytest but can't see a clear point on why I should rewrite all my test for pytest. If you have any  reading recommandation about testing python code that deals with api it would awesome.